# Errors in photoshops cs6 in wine

Tags: wine, photoshop

I usually meet the errors that shown below when use `photoshop cs6`, especially  typing `step backward` several times.and I have to focus close it and restart the program ,This was a bad experience.

I just want to know if I forget configure something when I install or It is the bug of `wine` for `photoshop cs6`?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wine installation of CS6 requires msxml3. Make sure you have winetricks installed then run

```
winetricks msxml3
```